# Rxjs Observable: Get HTTP data only for the first subscriber and cached data for the rest

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular13

I'm trying to implement user permissions in an Angular app, but to put it simple, this is the scenario:

Upon loading a `MainModule`, I make an HTTP request and store the data in the `localStorage`, so the next time I can retrieve the data from there. This logic is inside an `Observable`, to which I'm subscribing from several places.

The problem is, if two subscriptions are executed at the same time, two HTTP request will be made before I even have the chance to store the data in the localStorage.

That's it, but to explain it further...

I'd like to make the HTTP request only once, store the data in the localStorage and emit the value, and from the second subscriber onwards, ignore all this logic if possible and just return the last emitted value.

I tried to use a `BehaviorSubject`, but then I get the last emitted data when I re-enter the module (i.e. *user_A* logs out and *user_B* logs in). The Service I'm using is provided in `root`, I couldn't provide it in `MainModule` because I get DI errors in some guards I have there. I also read about the `share` operator, but I'm not really sure about how to use it.

**UPDATE** (adding to [@Nugu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648360/nugu)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72268496/2213798)):

The problem with `share` was that the piped observable was not completing, so I wrapped a subscription to `this.http.get<T>` that calls `.next(value)` and `.complete()`, inside an Observable, and now it's working. I also added the condition of localStorage before making the HTTP request.

Also, on every module re-enter, I still got the last emitted value, so I turned the function `getSomeData()` into a property to always get the same instance of the Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [share()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) operator to share source among multiple subscribers. This will make sure the response is shared among the many subscribers and prevent duplicate HTTP request.

```
getSomeData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>('/endpoint').pipe(share());
}
```

You could do an if condition before calling `getSomeData()` to check if the data is already available in the store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this is practical, but I like to share.
first you need 1 more subject

```
 loggingIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

Then inside `login()` service just trigger status like

```
 login(): void {
   this.loggingIn.next(true);
   // ....loging
   this.loggingIn.next(false);
 }
```

So `getUser()` go to be look like this

```
 getUser(): Observable<User> {
   return this.loggingIn.pipe(() => {
     return this.user.pipe(filter(user => user !== null));
   });
 }
```